# JavaScript: What is the equivalent of PHP's "$this->$somefunc()"?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to store the name of a function as string in JS, and invoke it from an object, pretty much like the PHP code below?

```
$this->$someFunc();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
this[someFunc]();
```

Answer (score 8):

Sure thing. Try this:

```
var f = "foo";
var result = obj[f]();
```

where `foo` is a method on `obj`, or

```
this[f]();
```

where `foo` is a method on the current instance.